# retrieve date from Mysql and spilt it to the specific list

Tags: php, mysql, html, date

i am trying to retrieve date from Mysql db to my html form in order to edit the records, now the way i used to insert the date into the database was getting Year - Month - Day each from a list and then unite them in one variable like this :

```
$dob = $_POST['Year'] . '-' . $_POST['Month'] . '-' .$_POST['Day'];
```

this will insert the value of `$dob` like this format 0000-00-00 in my table

the problem is that how i will retrieve this variable and split it each element to its specific list

what i tried seems useless and wrong which is this code

```
$row['userDateOfBirth'] = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day ;
```

then put each variable to (example:year)

```
<option value="1920" selected="selected"><? echo $year ; ?></option>
```

this did not work , how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got an actual date/datetime field, you can do the splitting inside MySQL:

```
SELECT YEAR(datefield), MONTH(datefield), DAY(datefield), etc...
```

which gives you three separate fields containing the individual date components. You could also do things like `explode('-', $datestr)` in PHP to decompose 'yyyy-mm-dd' into individual yyyy, mm, and dd chunks.

Lots of options, it's up to you to pick which one is easiest/best for your particular problem.

Comment: thank you so much , it worked :) , i exploded the fetched variable and then assign the values to an array .

Answer (score 1):

You can handle that on the client (php) side.

```
$year = date('Y', strtotime( $row['userDateOfBirth'] ) );
```

if you have an invalid date, $year will have 1970.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$row['userDateOfBirth'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($mysqlResultRow['dateField']));
```

Where basically you're telling the date() function to return a formatted string of the time passed to it, in this case created via strtotime().

[Date() reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). The above example returns the date in "2000-01-01", see the reference for selecting the appropriate format for your project.